# I can't make use of url with arguments in laravel

Tags: laravel

I am working with a rest API, and I cannot do the following query, it throws me an empty array and not the answer that I want to see:

```
 http://localhost/project-test/public/api/contactos/buscar?name=eric&surname=almendras
```

controller:

```
 public function buscar($name,$surname){
    $contacto = Contacto::where('name', $name,'surname',$surname)->get();
    return $contacto;
}
```

route: (api.php)

```
Route::get('contactos/buscar/{name}/{surname}','ContactosController@buscar');
```

Comment: I clarify that my Database is loaded, but when making the query http://localhost/project-test/public/api/contactos/buscar?name=eric&surname=almendras, it does not bring me to that contact, that is, it does not return it, only returns an empty array

Comment: `{name}` and `{surname}` are URL params: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-parameters and https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#dependency-injection-route-parameters, specified via `/eric/almendras` in your URL, but you're passing them as a Query String `?name=eric&surname=almendras`. Check the documentation and fix that (use one or the other, don't mix em up), and also fix your `where()` clause as instructed below.

Answer (score 2):

You define `name` and `surname` as url params, but you include it in query string.
To access it you need to use `Request` class:

```
 public function buscar(Request $request){

    $name = $request->input('name');
    $surname = $request->input('surname');

    $contacto = Contacto::where([
       'name' => $name,
       'surname' => $surname
    ])->get();

    return $contacto;
}
```

or change url to:

```
http://localhost/project-test/public/api/contactos/buscar/eric/almendras
```

Comment: I tried it in the 2 ways and it keeps returning an empty array

Comment: @EricEfrainAlmendrasArnez What additional debugging have you done? Have you inspected the values of `$name` and `$surname`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the 2 conditions in a separate where statement:

```
 $contacto = Contacto::where('name', $name)->where('surname',$surname)->get();
```

Comment: I just applied it, and it keeps returning an empty array, it does not show me when I contact eric almendras

Answer (score 0):

As Daniel says you need to get the parameters from the `Request`, you then have different options when querying the model.

You can put multiple where clauses in an array, as long as you want all the operators to be `=`, passed to a single `where`:

```
$contacto = Contacto::where([
    'name' => $name,
    'surname' => $surname
])->get();
```

or an array of arrays if you want to use different operators:

```
$contacto = Contacto::where([
    ['name', '=', $name],
    ['surname', '<>', $surname]
])->get();
```

or use multiple where functions

```
$contacto = Contacto::where('name', $name)
                    ->where('surname', $surname)
                    ->get();
```

or use Laravel's magic methods:

```
$contacto = Contacto::whereName($name)
                    ->whereSurname($surname)
                    ->get();
```